# Storing and displaying multiple select items

Tags: php, multiple-select

I am using a multiple select box as shown below:

```
<select multiple="pages" id="pages" name="pages[]">
    <option value="Home Page">Home Page</option>
    <option value="Contact Us">Contact Us</option>
    <option value="Support">Support</option>
</select>
```

The list of pages is generated from another table in the database.

At the moment I am imploding $_POST['pages'] and storing the string in the database. What is a more efficient method of storing the selected values?

And finally how can I still display all of the pages (retrieved from another table in the database) and have the pages that user selected, selected in that multiple select box.

E.g. A user has selected Contact Us - when displaying all of the pages on the edit page, the Contact Us entry is highlighted (selected).

Answer (score 0):

The normal is collapse all in an array and i think it's pretty good.

Here it is an example: http://www.onlinetools.org/tricks/using_multiple_select.php

Answer (score 0):

There isn't much more of an efficient way of storing `$_POST['pages']` into the database other than turning the attribute `value` into array locations.

```
$type = array("Home Page","Contact Us","Support");
```

To maintain the selected items (for a POST) using an array is perfect. For example:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "<select name=\"pages\" id=\"pages\" names=\"pages[]\">";
    foreach($t as $loc=>$type)
        echo "<option value=\"$loc\">$type</option>";
    echo "</select>";
}else{
    echo "<select name=\"pages\" id=\"pages\" names=\"pages[]\">";
     foreach($t as $loc=>$type)
        if($_POST['pages'] == $loc) //select that item
            echo "<option value=\"$loc\" selected=\"selected\">$type</option>";
        else
            echo "<option value=\"$loc\">$type</option>";
    echo "</select>":
}
```

Selecting the items based off of data from a database just replace in the `if` statement on line 9 `$loc` with the array location that you stored in the database.

Comment: For maximum portability, use just `selected` rather than `selected="selected"`.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I usually do, but It's not valid HTML

Comment: Yes it is. The HTML specification refers to this as the "minimized form", and mentions that many user agents only recognize this form. See http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/intro/sgmltut.html#h-3.3.4.2.

Comment: I am unable to get it working. The pages are stored in the database in this format `Home Page,Contact Us,Support` - I am unsure how to put them into an array `$loc`

Comment: @Hammo `$loc` references the index, you wouldn't put them into that array.